# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrt.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, windows-10, simulink, matlab-compiler

Currently I am building a model for Simulink Real-Time and have  Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers Community 2015 as my compiler for Simulink Real-Time. When I try to build my model it gives the following error:

```
### Linking ... 
    link.exe /nologo /dll /MANIFEST /OPT:NOREF /export:mexFunction /OUT:Test_Handler_sfun.mexw64 /map:"Test_Handler_sfun.map"      @Test_Handler_sfun.mol 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrt.lib' 
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe"' : return code '0x450' 
Stop.
```

Previously I also had this error, which is caused by the same problem I believe. I solved this in an very unelegant manner.

```
 C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
```

I have searched quite a bit on google. I found out that this is because of some files and/or libraries are now located in the Windows 10 SDK installation folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10) and that this path is not included in the compiler somehow. There are quite some solutions for when you are working in a Visual Studio project, but not when working with Matlab and or Simulink.

How do I make sure that the libraries and files can be found and opened by the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

My answer is rather for Windows 8.1 and VS2017. 
For me worked using the *Visual Studio Installer* (in All Programs) and modifying *Desktop development with C++* by adding *Windows 8.1 SDK and UCRT SDK*. The library was picked up automatically then.

Reference screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Answer (score 2):

Since you solved the missing header file in an "unelegant matter" I am going to suggest another unelegant solution to your current problem. I had the same problem, and adding the corresponding library path (`-L...` to the compile options helped:

```
mex -output mybinary 
    -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt"
    -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64"
```

Make sure to adjust it to the exact version of your Windows Kit (`10.0.10240.0` in my case), and target (`x64`).

Comment: This appears to be the best solution for msvc 2022